# How to execute sqlplus commands on ssh enabled unix machine from java code

Tags: java, unix, ssh, sqlplus

Hello all I have a requirement which should be accomplished from  a    java program .The requirement is as follows,

```
   1.Connect to an SSH enabled unix machine 
   2.Login to sqlplus on the unix machine
   3.execute sqlplus commands
   4.Come out.
```

I am able to complete the first two tasks but I don't have any idea    in completing the tasks in the 3 & 4 points.Any help will be well    appreciated

Comment: are you using a java ssh client implementation or simply invoking the ssh command?

Comment: I am using the code snippet given in the below link http://www.journaldev.com/246/java-program-to-run-shell-commands-on-ssh-enabled-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet you post, set the command1 var for example to

```
String command1= "echo 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;' | sqlplus user/password@tnsname";
```

Comment: Perfect.Thanks a lot.please answer one more question.How can I execute multiple sql commands using this